# Node express server not serving images folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, ejs

When I run my bundled React app on the production server, it can't find my image files and I'm not sure why. I'm fairly sure it's got something to do with my node express configuration and/or my `.ejs` template file.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.render("index");
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Production Server</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=BenchNine" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="../static/js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My CSS stylesheet is called in the template file, and all JS is bundled into `bundle.js` which is referenced in the script tag. I'm not sure how to get my application to recognise the `/img` folder though, as at the moment it doesn't.

Here's my file structure:

```
- static
   - css
      - main.css
   - js
      - bundle.js
   - img (contains all image files)
```

When I run the app however, and I open 'Sources' in Chrome console, the /img file is not being served.

I thought this line indicates that express serves everything in the `/static` folder...

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

...yet only two out of three files are being served.

Would massively appreciate if anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong with my setup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your js / css being loaded ok?

Comment: Yep, both of those are fine.

Comment: /img doesn't exist, it'll be /static/img - or am i missing something?

Comment: Yeah that's right, it's `static/img`, but I thought that everything in the `static` folder should be served, including all subfolders, one of which is `/img`... or am I getting that wrong?

Comment: You don't actually load in any image files though? It's not shown in the Sources tab then.

Comment: @FabianSchultz - how would I load the image files then? I can load the bundle.js in a `<script>` tag and css in a `<link>` tag, but images are just loaded in `<img>` tags within the application itself... As it stands, the JSX is trying to reference image files that don't exist, as they are not being served in the first place. This is the part I don't know how to do.

Comment: So to be clear: The image requests result in a 404? Check the console to be sure.

Comment: It doesn't specify 404 anywhere I can see, but I guess that is what it is. The client is requesting a file and the server cannot find it.

Comment: If there's no 404 in the console or your network tab it's an issue on the frontend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132578/discussion-between-paulos3000-and-fabian-schultz).

Comment: Could it be an issue with unnecessary `..` in `../static/css/main.css`? I am pretty sure you can't traverse to `..` from a root request you make to your `/index` page. Could you verify that? Just replace with `/static/css/main.css`.

Comment: The css is loading fine, so that can't be the problem. So is the `bundle.js` file which uses the same path.

Answer (score 2):

The source tab in the DevTools will only show the contents that are being used by the browser in your case index.ejs, it's only using .js and .css files

in Index.ejs you are loading

`<script src="../static/js/bundle.js"></script>` and                                 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css">`

so that means the middleware `app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));` will check whether or not the `/js/bundle.js` and `/css/main.css` are there in the static folder, if yes it will serve them, if not then will give file or folder not found.

That means whatever you will load from the static folder in index.ejs or use in index.ejs only that contents and files will be present in the source tab.
Try adding a image in index.ejs from static folder and then view the source tab

or remove `<script src="../static/js/bundle.js"></script>` and view source tab you won't see JS folder as it's not been used by index.ejs

> Always reload the server

Comment: I've tried that - and it works. However I want to load images from my react jsx code, which exists in `bundle.js` - this loads ok as my React app loads as desired, but for some reason the `img` tags in this code do not reference the image files in my file tree.

Comment: that's some kind of path issues.